# PDF Box getXObjectNames() does not recognize bar code on my PDF, however it does recognize it on a PDF file I got off the internet

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to fetch and read bar codes from my PDF using `getXObjectNames()` of PdResources.

- My code is very similar to this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2124

If you see the above JIRA item, you will see a PDF file attached to it.
When I run the code on that PDF file I get the desired output (i.e. the bar code type is printed.)

However when I run it on my PDF, it does not recognize the bar code in it.  (I have checked that the bar code is in fact an image and not text.)

Also it may sound weird, but it did work on my PDF *once* and I haven't made any changes since then, but it definitely does *not* work now.  (I cannot share the PDF for some reason.)

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

*Also this is my first question on Stack Overflow. Please tell me if I am wrong anywhere.*

Here is a link to that pdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PzVApIePg4U9XL399BpAd2oeY6Q2tLEB/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I checked your example file but PDFBox properly extracts the QR code image, see the edit to my question below. Thus, I cannot reproduce your issue "PDF Box getXObjectNames() does not recognize bar code on my PDF" because obviously it does.

Answer (score 2):

#### In General

As you don't show your code but only describe it as *very similar* to that in [PDFBOX-2124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2124), and as you say you *cannot share the PDF for some reason*, I only have that code to analyze. Thus, I cannot tell what really is the issue but merely enumerate some possible problems

First of all, that code only inspects the immediate resources of the given page for bitmap images:

```
PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();

Map<String, PDXObject> xobjects = (Map<String, PDXObject>) pdResources.getXObjects();
if (xobjects != null)
{
    for (String key : xobjects.keySet())
    {
        PDXObject xobject = xobjects.get(key);
        if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
        {
            PDImageXObject imageObject = (PDImageXObject) xobject;
            String suffix = imageObject.getSuffix();
            if (suffix != null)
            {
                BufferedImage image = imageObject.getImage();
                extractBarcodeArrayByAreas(image, this.maximumBlankPixelDelimiterCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([PDFBOX-2124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2124) [PdPageBarcodeScanner](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12648868/PdPageBarcodeScanner.java) method `scsan`)*

Bitmap images can also be stored elsewhere, e.g.

- in the separate resources of form xobjects, patterns, or Type 3 fonts used on the page; to find them one has to inspect other page resources, too, even recursively as the image might be a resource of a pattern used in a form xobject used on the page;
- in the separate resources of annotations of the page; thus, one has to recurse into annotation resources, too;
- inlined in some content stream; thus, one also has to search the content streams of the page itself, of page resources (recursively), and page annotations and their resources (recursively).

Furthermore, the bitmap might be given in some format (in particular with some colorspace) which PDFBox does not know how to export as `BufferedImage`.

Also the bar code may be constructed using some mask applied to a purely black bitmap in which case your code probably only tries to scan that purely black image.

Furthermore, you say

> I have checked that the bar code is in fact an image and not text.

If you only checked that the bar code is *not text*, it may not only be a *bitmap image* but it can also be drawn by *vector graphics* instructions. Thus, you also have to check all content streams for vector graphics instructions drawing a bar code.

Also there may be combinations, e.g. a soft mask of vector graphics may be active when drawing a purely black inlined bitmap image etc.

And I'm sure I've missed a number of options here.

---

As next step you may want to analyze the *PDF you cannot share* to find out how exactly that barcode is drawn.

Alternatively, you render the page as bitmap image and search that large bitmap for bar codes using zxing.

---

#### `Sample PDF.pdf`

You provided a link to a sample PDF. So I tried to extract the bar code using code *very similar* to that from [PDFBOX-2124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2124). Apparently the code there was for some PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, so it had to be corrected a bit. In particular the method `getXObjectNames()` you mention in the question title finally is used:

```
PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();
int index = 0;

for (COSName name : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
    PDXObject xobject = pdResources.getXObject(name);
    if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
    {
        PDImageXObject imageObject = (PDImageXObject) xobject;
        String suffix = imageObject.getSuffix();
        if (suffix != null)
        {
            BufferedImage image = imageObject.getImage();

            File file = new File(RESULT_FOLDER, String.format("Sample PDF-1-%s.%s", index, imageObject.getSuffix()));
            ImageIO.write(image, imageObject.getSuffix(), file);
            index++;
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
}
```

*([ExtractImages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractImages.java#L332) test `testExtractSamplePDFJayshreeAtak`)*

The output: One bitmap image is exported as "Sample PDF-1-0.tiff" which looks like this:

[image: image as png]

Thus, I cannot reproduce your issue

> PDF Box getXObjectNames() does not recognize bar code on my PDF, however it does recognize it on a PDF file I got off the internet

Obviously `getXObjectNames()` does return the name of the bitmap image xobject resource and PDFBox exports it just fine.

Please check with your code whether as claimed the image is not extracted or whether some later step simply cannot deal with it.

If in your case indeed the image is not extracted,

- update your PDFBox version (I used the current development head but the newest released version should return the same),
- update your Java,
- check whether you have extra JAI jars that might cause trouble.

If in your case the image is extracted but not analyzed as expected by later code,

- debug more thoroughly to find out where the analysis fails,
- create a new question here focusing on the QR code image analysis,
- and provide enough code and the tiff file to allow people to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect an answer so fast. Thanks for replying. I'll go through this answer and tell you if it works.

Comment: Well, essentially the answer tells you that without the PDF to analyze, one can only guess...

Comment: I'll go one step further, if your PDF file contains a high-quality barcode, it *should* be in the PDF as vector elements. And those definitely do not have to be grouped in an XObject. I'm affiliated with a tool that adds barcodes to PDF documents and that doesn't mark those at all, it just generates page content that is vector or vector and text (depending on the barcode type).

Comment: Indeed, HQ barcodes should really be drawn as vector graphics.

Comment: @mkl I have added a link to the PDF.

Comment: The PDFBOX version I am using is 2.0.18. Also my code is not "very similar", it's exactly similar to the link I shared. Hence I did not feel the need to paste the code here. I'll debug/analyze this more, based on the points you have mentioned.

Comment: *'The PDFBOX version I am using is 2.0.18. Also my code is not "very similar", it's exactly similar to the link I shared.'* - That's not plausible. The code attached to issue [PDFBOX-2124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2124) does not compile or run with PDFBox 2.0.18. For example the method `pdResources.getXObjects` used in that code does not exist in PDFBox 2.0.18 anymore, instead one uses `getXObjectNames`. And according to your question title you do so, too, which also shows that you don't use the exact code from that issue.

Comment: Ah, @JayshreeAtak, I just saw that the "My code is very similar to this link" has been edited into your question by Olivia Stork while you originally said "My code is every bit as similar to that in the link". Actually, though, I would have interpreted your formulation just like Olivia, that you meant "very similar". In particular as you mentioned an issue in a method `getXObjectNames` not used in the linked code.